# Algorithm for approximating the 2D Look-up table

Tags: algorithm, math, approximation

What would be a good algorithm or analytical method to approximate a discrete 2D look-up-table (LUT) to a continuous function? That is, given `z=LUT[x1][x2]` and we wanna come up with a function such that `z=f(x1, x2)`.

Comment: It just depends what you are trying to approximate. What is your lookup table for? You gave no indication on what you want, other than it maps a space of two variables onto an output of one value. You can just use the continuous function with a set of discrete values, and actually make a lookup table, of course. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: To elaborate, if the continuous function is a polynomial, then a large enough table will let find the values exactly.  Or if it's a trigonometric polynomial.  If you have bounds on the derivatives, then you can get better results.  If you only have continuity, then all you can do is linearly interpolate.

Comment: Your two sentences seem contradictory: The first sentence appears to imply that you are trying to approximate a continuous function via a LUT, the second sentence asks for a continuous function that approximates a function specified via LUT. Which case are you actually interested in?

Comment: @Jes Take a look at [Reverse complex 2D lookup table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29227551/2521214) it is very similar problem so it might help. Without knowing the properties of your LUT is **very hard** to estimate the `Z` properly see  [Finding the mathematical algorithm to which matches an input and output together](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31510038/2521214) and that is just 1D. If nothing works you still can do piecewise bilinear/bicubic interpolation ...