# Convert plot to equation

Tags: vb.net, excel, math

I am working on a project that requires me to derive equations for some plots that I would get. Here I want to use an accelerometer to get a reading on the points in the Cartesian coordinates and use these to find the equations of the plot for further analysis of the equations.

The reading would be for the vibrations made by an object for which the vibration needs to be damped.

Currently I did not get any method to change a plot from excel to a mathematical equation. The plot points were derived from a smartphone app.

Equations for all three coordinates XYZ can be calibrated separately.

I am in dire need for a vb.net code to change the plot into equation. the charts would be an input to excel.

Any and all help is appreciated.
Thank You

PS. Please explain if posting a code.

Comment: You'll need to do fitting of some kind.  I won't be posting any code.

Comment: You are describing regression analysis. It comes in lots of flavors, multiple regression, polynomial regression, etc. You may need a combination of both.

Comment: without seeing sample input data is very hard to recommend anything take a look at very similar (if not duplicate) QA: [Finding the mathematical algorithm to which matches an input and output together](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31510038/2521214). You should attack this parametricaly on per axis basis because I got the feeling your input data will not be functions but 3D curves instead. If all fails you still can do piecewise cubic interpolation/fit ...