# Preferred means for finding common tangent to a pair of ellipses in C++

Tags: c++, geometry, solver

I want to do this in C++.  I have got two ideas by which I can do this:

1. Considering the pair of ellipses as parametric equations of two different parameters, I can get two equations in terms of the two parameters.  This pair of equations is non-linear, both functions of cotangents, sines and cosines.  Geant4, which is what I am primarily working with, only has Polynomial
2. Use a geometry library to solve this problem.  I looked at Boost geometry, but the documentation is incoherent (to me).  Having said that, it seems more aimed at computational geometry.  Perhaps I am asking it to do Y, when it was only ever meant to do X.

How might one go about this?  In python it is so easy, I could do it in my sleep. Any insight would be much appreciated.  Since I've taken up C++, it feels like picking the library to use is a huge battle in itself.

Comment: What is common tangent of pair of ellipsis? (which one there may be more then one) Add a sketch example image. What are the constraints of solution what ellipses you have (axis aligned or generic)  Ellipses are tricky and many geometric problems we do not know how to compute algebraically instead numerical, graphic and approximation methods are used (because of the transcendental system of equations) look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29166819/2521214) for example approach how to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a few suggestions. You might try LibreCAD, which has a solver for common tangents to two ellipses, but I don't know anything about the API. The solver solves quartic equations, which is what you obtain if you naively try to find the common tangents for two ellipses.

If you want to roll your own: With a little bit of theory ("ranges of conics"), what you are asking for can be done with linear algebra (namely, finding inverses of 3x3 matrices) plus solving quadratics and one cubic equation. It goes like this:

You can express any conic (such as an ellipse) in the form of a matrix equation

```
        [m00 m01 m02] [x]
[x,y,z] [m10 m11 m12] [y] = 0
        [m20 m21 m22] [z]
```

where the matrix `M` is symmetric and `[x,y,z]` are homogeneous coordinates; just think `z=1`. We can write that equation in short form as `X M X^T = 0` where `X^T` is the transpose of `X`.

Lines in the plane can be written in the form `lx+my+nz=0` and so have "line coordinates" `(l,m,n)`.

The set of tangent lines to the above conic can be expressed very simply in this notation. Let `A` be the inverse of the matrix `M`. The set of tangent lines to the conic is then

```
        [a00 a01 a02] (l)
(l,m,n) [a10 a11 a12] (m) = 0
        [a20 a21 a22] (n)
```

Now suppose we have a second conic with matrix `N`, and that `N` has inverse `B`. A common tangent will satisfy the above equation and the equation

```
        [b00 b01 b02] (l)
(l,m,n) [b10 b11 b12] (m) = 0
        [b20 b21 b22] (n)
```

In fact, we can scalar multiply the matrix in the latter equation by `t` and it will still hold:

```
          [b00 b01 b02] (l)
(l,m,n) t [b10 b11 b12] (m) = 0
          [b20 b21 b22] (n)
```

Adding the equation for the tangents to the first conic to the above equation for the second conic, we have the matrix equation `L (A + tB) L^T = 0`. So any common tangent to the two conics is a common tangent to every conic in the "range" `A + tB`.

Now for the big simplifying idea: we can find some very special conics in that range, "degenerate" conics, which are just pairs of points. Since the common tangents must pass through all conics, it follows that they must pass through the degenerate conics. But it is easy to find the lines that pass through degenerate conics, since such conics are just pairs of points!

You find the degenerate conics by solving the cubic equation `det(A + tB) = 0` where `det()` is the determinant of 3x3 matrices. The cubic can be solved in closed form by Cardano's formula or a variation, or it can be solved numerically if that's what you need. Once you find the value(s) of `t` which make degenerate conics, you can factorize the equation `L (A + tB) L^T = 0` into two linear factors. Each linear factor `xl + ym + zn = 0` defines a point in homogeneous coordinates `[x,y,z]`, or in Cartesian coordinates `(x/z,y/z)`. You should get three point-pairs in this manner (six points). Taking lines through certain of those point-pairs will give you your four (at most) tangent lines.

Here is a simple example (where the centres of the two ellipses are both at the origin): find the common tangents to `x^2+2y^2=3` and `x^2+14y^2=7`. The conic in matrix form are

```
        [1 0  0] [x]               [1  0  0] [x]
[x,y,z] [0 2  0] [y] = 0,  [x,y,z] [0 14  0] [y] = 0
        [0 0 -3] [z]               [0  0 -7] [z]
```

The tangents are given by

```
        [6 0  0] (l)               [14 0  0] (l)
(l,m,n) [0 3  0] (m) = 0,  (l,m,n) [ 0 1  0] (m) = 0
        [0 0 -2] (n)               [ 0 0 -2] (n)
```

Note I have multiplied the inverse matrices by a scalar just to make the entries integers rather than rational numbers. You don't have to do that but it makes the hand calculations easier. Multiplying the second matrix by an additional scalar `t` gives

```
        [6+14t 0    0   ] (l)
(l,m,n) [0     3+t  0   ] (m) = 0
        [0     0   -2-2t] (n)
```

The conic is degenerate when `(6+14t)(3+t)(-2-2t)=0`, i.e., when `t=-3/7, -3, -1`. When `t=-3/7` we get

```
18/7 m^2 - 8/7 n^2 = 2/7 (9 m^2 - 4 n^2) = 2/7 (3m - 2n)(3m + 2n) = 0
```

This corresponds to the points with homogeneous coordinates `[x,y,z] = [0,3,-2]` and `[0,3,2]`, in other words to points with Cartesian coordinates `(0,-3/2)` and `(0,3/2)`.

When `t=-3` we get `-36l^2 + 4n^2 = (6l+2n)(-6l+2n) = 0`, points `[6,0,2]` and `[-6,0,2]` or in Cartesian coordinates `(3,0)` and `(-3,0)`. Finally, when `t=1` we get `-8l^2 + 2m^2 = 2(2l+m)(-2l+m) = 0` corresponding to points `[2,1,0]` and `[-2,1,0]` which are points at infinity.

Avoiding the points at infinity for now, just because they're a little more difficult to work with, we get four lines through the following pairs of points:

```
{(0,-3/2),(-3,0)}, {(0,-3/2),(3,0)}, {(0,3/2),(-3,0)}, {(0,3/2),(3,0)}
```

which give us the four common tangents to the two ellipses.

[image: common tangents to two ellipses]

You can see from the picture that the common tangents also pass through the points at infinity `[2,1,0]` and `[-2,1,0]`, i.e., that the pairs of parallel lines have slope `1/2` and `-1/2`.

Isn't that beautiful?

Comment: I have a question about the penultimate step:


_Once you find the value(s) of t which make degenerate conics, you can factorize the equation L (A + tB) L^T = 0 into two linear factors._


What do you mean by this?  Sorry if this seems trivial to you, however my linear algebra game is a bit rusy.  After this it's a matter of connecting indivial points two each other, of which up to 4 will be common tangents, correct?  Thanks though, I love the elegance of this solution (once I fully understand it, of course!)

Comment: Hi, I've given it more thought and it seems that the conics generated in your suggest example by det(A+Bt)=0 are of course degenerate, but none are points.  Two pairs are parallel lines and one pair is an intersecting line.  I think I must be missing something.  Thanks.

Comment: The equation *L (A + tB) L^T = 0* is a quadratic form involving terms *l^2, m^2, n^2, lm, mn, nl*. Normally (when the graph of the quadratic form is a non-degenerate conic) the form does not factor into two linear factors. When the form is degenerate (determinant of matrix vanishes) the form factors. One way you can factor is by using the quadratic formula: consider *l* to be the variable, say, and *m,n* to be constants. You are correct about connecting the points; 6 points give 15 pairs, 3 of which are irrelevant (points which come from the same t). 4 of the other 12 give common tangents.

Comment: @rooms: Regarding how degenerate line conics define points: you're thinking about how degenerate point conics are pairs of lines. What we have here is degenerate line conics which are pairs of points. The situation is dual. It can be confusing because folks seem to have forgotten about duality, line conics and other beautiful ideas in projective geometry. I can't even find a single comprehensive reference published in the last 100 years, though I did pull the example from one old book on Google books.