# Finding inner common tangent to a pair of conics

Tags: c++, matlab, geometry, projective-geometry

I have been trying to get the common tangents to two rotated ellipse. I was following the method given by [Edward Doolittle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4731679/edward-doolittle) in the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668231/preferred-means-for-finding-common-tangent-to-a-pair-of-ellipses-in-c/31671423#31671423?newreg=10f34fb450f3426f8092a0023b95896c). The two ellipses are given as the equation given in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse).

In the Matrix form the ellipse can be shown as this:
[image: Equation 1]

First ellipse is centered at (0,0) rotated by 45 degrees with semi-major and semi-minor axes length as 2,1. Second ellipse is centered at (15,0), rotated by 120 degrees with semi-major and semi-minor axes length as 3,1

Linear combination of the adjoint matrices of the two ellipses are per dual of two ellipse combined
[image: Equation 2]
I am getting this value
[image: Equation 3].

Then I tried to find to find the value of t which will make the conic (above matrix) degenerate.

I found the value of t to be (-0.05,0.29,2.46). However, when I put these values back into the above matrix I am not able to reduce the matrix to two variables form. I am always dealing with 3 variables. For example, if I put t = -0.05 then I get the following:

[image: Adj. Matrix]

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Your question is tagged C++ and Matlab but there is no code for either. Perhaps you are looking for https://math.stackexchange.com/? If this is a coding problem then please include your code. If you do post to math, please include the equations directly instead of linking to images.

Comment: I have Matlab code but didn't include because it is spreaded in multiple files. But I have explained everything thoroughly and included the link to where I am referring as well. So it should be self explanatory to the reader what am I talking about. Yes, it is more or less a math problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to finding an algorithm for solving a system of two quadratic equations of two variables, by interpreting it as a projective geometry pencil of conics, then finding the three degenerate conics of the pencil together with a projective transformation that simplifies these three degenerate conics to the point of your being able to read off the solutions very easily in new simplifying coordinate system, and after that transforming them back to the original coordinate system.

I sketched an algorithm in python, I think it seems to work on your example... but I was in a hurry and did not check it properly, so there may be bugs...

```
import numpy as np
import math

# technical module, functions, details
def homogenize(x):
    return np.array([x[0], x[1], 1])

def cos_sin(angle_deg):
    return math.cos(angle_deg*math.pi/180), math.sin(angle_deg*math.pi/180)

def rotation(cs_sn):
    return np.array([[cs_sn[0], -cs_sn[1]], 
                     [cs_sn[1],  cs_sn[0]]])

# defining the isometry (the rotation plus translation) transformation
# between the coordinate system aligned with the conic and a general (world) 
# coordinate system
def isom_inverse(angle, translation):
    '''
    isometry from conic-aligned coordinate system (conic attached)
    to global coordinate system (world system) 
    '''
    cos_, sin_ = cos_sin(angle)
    return np.array([[cos_, -sin_, translation[0]], 
                     [sin_,  cos_, translation[1]], 
                     [   0,     0,             1]])
    
def isom(angle, translation):
    '''
    isometry from global coordinate system (world system) 
    to conic-aligned coordinate system (conic attached) 
    '''
    cos_, sin_ = cos_sin(-angle)
    tr = - rotation((cos_, sin_)).dot(translation)
    return np.array([[ cos_, -sin_, tr[0]], 
                     [ sin_,  cos_, tr[1]], 
                     [    0,     0,    1 ]])

# calculating the coinc defined by a pair of axes' lengts, 
# axes rotation angle and center of the conic  
def Conic(major, minor, angle, center):
    D = np.array([[minor**2,        0,                 0],
                  [       0, major**2,                 0], 
                  [       0,        0, -(minor*major)**2]])
    U = isom(angle, center)
    return (U.T).dot(D.dot(U))     

# calculating the coinc dual to the conic defined by a pair of axes' lengths, 
# axes rotation angle and center of the conic  
def dual_Conic(major, minor, angle, center):
    D_1 = np.array([[major**2,        0,  0], 
                    [       0, minor**2,  0], 
                    [       0,        0, -1]])
    U_1 =  isom_inverse(angle, center)
    return (U_1).dot(D_1.dot(U_1.T)) 

# transforming the matrix of a conic into a vector of six coefficients
# of a quadratic equation with two variables
def conic_to_equation(C):
    '''
    c[0]*x**2 + c[1]*x*y + c[2]*y**2 + c[3]*x + c[4]*y + c[5] = 0
    '''
    return np.array([C[0,0], 2*C[0,1], C[1,1], 2*C[0,2], 2*C[1,2], C[2,2]])    

# transforming the vector of six coefficients
# of a quadratic equation with two variables into a matrix of 
# the corresponding conic 
def equation_to_conic(eq):
    '''
    eq[0]*x**2 + eq[1]*x*y + eq[2]*y**2 + eq[3]*x + eq[4]*y + eq[5] = 0
    '''
    return np.array([[2*eq[0],   eq[1],   eq[3]],
                     [  eq[1], 2*eq[2],   eq[4]],
                     [  eq[3],   eq[4], 2*eq[5]]]) / 2

# given a point (x,y) define the vector (x^2, xy, y^2, x, y, 1)    
def argument(x):
    return np.array([x[0]**2, x[0]*x[1], x[1]**2, x[0], x[1], 1])

# given x = (x[0],x[1]) calculate the value of the quadratic equation with
# six coefficients coeff
def quadratic_equation(x, coeff):
    '''
    coeff[0]*x**2 + coeff[1]*x*y + coeff[2]*y**2 + coeff[3]*x + coeff[4]*y + coeff[5] = 0
    '''
    return coeff.dot( argument(x) )    

# given a pair of conics, as a pair of symmetric matrices, 
# calculate the vector k = (k[0], k[1], k[2]) of values for each of which 
# the conic c1 - k[i]*c2 from the pencil of conics c1 - t*c2 
# is a degenerate conic (the anti-symmetric product of a pair of linear forms) 
# and also find the matrix U 
# of the projective transformation that simplifies the geometry of 
# the pair of conics, the geometry of the pencil c1 - t*c2 in general, 
# as well as the geometry of the three degenerate conics in particular    
def transform(c1, c2):
    '''
    c1 and c2 are 3 by 3 symmetric matrices of the two conics
    '''
    c21 = np.linalg.inv(c2).dot(c1)
    k, U = np.linalg.eig(c21)
    return k, U

# the same as before, but for a pair of equations instead of matrices of conics
def eq_transform(eq1, eq2):
    '''
    eq1 and eq2 = np.array([eq[0], eq[1], eq[2], eq[3], eq[4], eq[5]])
    '''
    C1 = equation_to_conic(eq1)
    C2 = equation_to_conic(eq2)
    return transform(C1, C2)

# realizing the matrix U as a projective transformation
def proj(U, x):
    if len(x) == 2:
        x = homogenize(x)
    y = U.dot(x)
    y = y / y[2]
    return y[0:2]

# find the common points, i.e. points of intersection of a pair of conics
# represented by a pair of symmetric matrices
def find_common_points(c1, c2):
    k, U = transform(c1, c2)
    L1 = (U.T).dot((c1 - k[0]*c2).dot(U))
    L2 = (U.T).dot((c1 - k[1]*c2).dot(U))
    sol = np.empty((4,3), dtype=float)
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            sol[i+2*j,0:2] = np.array([math.sqrt(abs(L2[2,2] / L2[0,0]))*(-1)**i, math.sqrt(abs(L1[2,2] / L1[1,1]))*(-1)**j])
            sol[i+2*j,0:2] = proj(U, sol[i+2*j,0:2])
    sol[:,2] = np.ones(4)
    return sol

# find the solutions, i.e. the points x=(x[0],x[1]) saisfying the pair 
# of quadratic equations 
# represented by a pair of vectors eq1 and eq2 of 6 coefficients
def solve_eq(eq1, eq2):
    conic1 = equation_to_conic(eq1)
    conic2 = equation_to_conic(eq2)
    return find_common_points(conic1, conic2)


'''
Esample of finding the common tangents of a pair of conics:
conic 1: major axis = 2, minor axis = 1, angle = 45, center = (0,0)
conic 2: major axis = 3, minor axis = 1, angle = 120, center = (15,0)
'''

a = 2
b = 1
cntr = np.array([0,0])
w = 45

Q1 = Conic(a, b, w, cntr)
dQ1 = dual_Conic(a, b, w, cntr)

a = 3
b = 1
cntr = np.array([15,0])
w = 120

Q2 = Conic(a, b, w, cntr)
dQ2 = dual_Conic(a, b, w, cntr)

R = find_common_points(dQ1, dQ2)

print('')
print(R)
print('')
print('checking that the output forms common tangent lines: ')
print('')
print('conic 1: ')
print(np.diagonal(R.dot(dQ1.dot(R.T))) )
print('')
print('conic 2: ')
print(np.diagonal(R.dot(dQ2.dot(R.T))) )
#conic_to_equation(dQ1)
```

**Some Explanations:** Assume you want to find the intersection points of two conics C1 and C2. Let us assume for simplicity that they are real ellipses that intersect in four different points (to avoid complex numbers)

In the case of finding the common tangents to a pair of conics,
simply convert the two conics two corresponding duals and then find the intersection points
of the duals. These intersection points are the equation coefficients of the tangents of the original conics.

There are possibly several different geometric interpretations of this problem, but let us go with the pencil of conics. The two conics C1 and C2 are represented by 3 by 3 symmetric matrices with non-zero determinants, which I have denoted C1 and C2. The linear combination, called pencil of conics generated by C1 and C2, is the t-parametrized family of conics `C1 - t*C2` , where t is just a number. What is crucial is that every conic `C1 - tC2` passes through the intersection points of C1 and C2 and these are the only four points they all have in common. You can prove this by observing that if `x.T * C1 * x = x.T * C1 * x = 0` then
`x.T * (C1 - t*C2) * x = x.T * C1 * x - t * x.T * C2 * x = 0 - t*0 = 0`. Furthermore, if you take an intersection point of `C1` and `C1 - t*C2`, then `C2 = C1 - t*C2 + s*C2` you can apply the same argument when `s = t`.

In this family of conics, there are three degenerate conics, that are geometrically three pairs of lines. They occur exactly when t is such that `det( C1 - t*C2 ) = 0`. This is a polynomial equation of degree 3 with respect to t, so there are three, say different solutions `k[0], k[1], k[2],` due to the niceness of the C1 and C2. Projectively speaking, each degenerate conic `C1 - k[j]*C2` is a pair of lines and they have a common intersection point `u[:,j] = [ u[0,j] : u[1,j] : u[2,j] ]`. Moreover, `rank(C1 - k[j]*C2) = 2`, so `ker(C1 - k[j]*C2) = 1`. This point `u[:,j]` is characterized as a solution to the equation
`(C1 - k[j]*C2) * u[:,j] = 0`.
Since `C2` is invertible (non-degenerate), multiply both sides of the equation by `inverse(C2)` and obtain the equivalent equation `( (inverse(C2) * C1) - k[j]*Identity ) * u[:,j] = 0` which is an eigenvalue equation, with `k[j]` as eigenvalue and `u[:,j]` as eigenvector. The output of the function `transform()` is the 1 by 3 array `k` of eigenvalues and the 3 by 3 matrix `U = [ u[:,0], u[:,1], u[:,2] ]` of eigenvectors.

Conjugating `C1 - k[j]*C2 by U, i.e. (U.T)*(C1 - k[j]*C2)*U`, is geometrically equivalent to performing a projective transformation that sends `u[:,0]` and `u[:,1]` to infinity and `u[:,2]` to the origin. Thus, `U` changes the coordinate system from a general one to a special coordinate system, in which two of the degenerate conics are given by pairs of parallel lines and combined they intersect in a rectangle. The third conic is represeneted by the diagnols of the rectangle.

In this new picture, the intersection problem can be easily solved, just by reading off one solution from the entries of the matrices `(U.T)*(C1 - k[j]*C2)*U` (the intersection points are the vertices of the rectangle, so if you find one of them, the others are simply mirror symmetric of each other).

Comment: Hello @Futurologist,

Thanks for the reply! Can you please explain what are you doing in the function transform. And if possible please shed some light on the linear algebra employed to obtain the solution.

Comment: @KashishDhal I have added some explanations.

Comment: Thanks, do you recommend any material (books etc) to read to understand projective geometry concepts better which we are talking about here?

Comment: Hello @Futurologist, Is there any way to find the angle between inner tangent lines without getting the point of intersection with the conics?

Comment: @KashishDhal Honestly, I do not know off the top of my head, but there may very well be such a method. I am just not aware of it at this moment and I have not thought about it enough.

Comment: @KashishDhal Hold on, maybe I misunderstood here. Are you asking if one can find the angle between the inner tangents without finding some kind of representation for the common tangents (like say normal vectors) in the first place, or are you asking if the angle can be found without trying to find  the points of tangency of each tangent with the conics?

Comment: @KashishDhal Actually, if you open a new question explaining exactly what your final goal is and how exactly the conics are represented (as equations, or as positions of centers and angles of axes with the coordinate axes, etc...), then maybe people can try to help you  more, instead of asking about subproblems as bits and pieces of how you think the final goal should be approached.

Comment: please have a look on this link, if you think you may be able to help! Thanks!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025052/how-to-get-the-angle-between-the-inner-common-tangents-to-two-conics-if-four-hom

Comment: is there any way to cite this article? I can see a cite option on mathstackexchange but not here stackoverflow. Please let me know.

Comment: Also, I wanted to know that how you are reading the vertices of rectangle in special coordinate system in the line here, 
np.array([math.sqrt(abs(L2[2,2] / L2[0,0]))*(-1)**i, math.sqrt(abs(L1[2,2] / L1[1,1]))*(-1)**j])

Comment: @Futurologist Thanks for this amazing solution. Not sure to fully understand the concept of projectivity, but my question is simple: how do I get the equation of the four tangents in the cartesian referenciel of the 2 initial ellipsis?